# Wint-in-bool-context what causes this warning?

Tags: c++, vivado-hls

I have searched on google but I have no luck to find the cause of this warning `Wint-in-bool-context`

The compiler gives me the following warning:

```cpp
In file included from /tools/Xilinx/Vivado/2020.1/include/ap_common.h:641,
                 from /tools/Xilinx/Vivado/2020.1/include/ap_int.h:54,
                 from src/matrix_mult.h:35,
                 from src/host.cpp:33:
/tools/Xilinx/Vivado/2020.1/include/etc/ap_private.h: In instantiation of 'void ap_private<_AP_W, _AP_S, true>::clearUnusedBits() volatile [with int _AP_W = 32; bool _AP_S = true]':
/tools/Xilinx/Vivado/2020.1/include/etc/ap_private.h:1485:1:   required from 'ap_private<_AP_W, _AP_S, true>& ap_private<_AP_W, _AP_S, true>::operator=(int) [with int _AP_W = 32; bool _AP_S = true]'
/tools/Xilinx/Vivado/2020.1/include/ap_int.h:160:3:   required from 'ap_int<_AP_W>::ap_int(int) [with int _AP_W = 32]'
src/host.cpp:50:30:   required from here
/tools/Xilinx/Vivado/2020.1/include/etc/ap_private.h:2144:28: warning: enum constant in boolean context [-Wint-in-bool-context]
 2144 |             : (excess_bits ? (((uint64_t)VAL) << (excess_bits)) >> (excess_bits)
      |               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
 2145 |                            : (uint64_t)VAL));
```

This is the code line related with this warning (host.cpp line 50) :

```cpp
#include <ap_int.h>; //This is a library for arbitrary precision integers Xilinx HLS

int M,N

static void initialise(ap_int<32> *A)
{
     for (int i = 0; i < M; i++) {
          for (int j = 0; j < N; j++) {
               A[i * N + j] =  1; // _this is line 50_
          }
     }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  N = atoi(argv[0]); //user input the matrix sizes during run
  M = atoi(argv[1]);
std::vector<ap_int<32>,aligned_allocator<ap_int<32>> A(N*M);

initialise(A.data());
```

The target is creating 32 bit integer valued vector to store a matrix with N*M size.

Comment: I have updated the code to include a snippet

Answer (score 1):

`-Wint-in-bool-context` is exactly as it sounds. You're using an integer value and allowing it to behave implicitly like a `bool` (e.g. any nonzero value is `true`).

In your (limited) snippet, it's likely because `excess_bits` is an integral value and not `bool`. To silence such a warning, explicitly cast instead, or perform a check that evaluates to a boolean expression -- such as:

```cpp
              : (static_cast<bool>(excess_bits) ? (((uint64_t)VAL) << (excess_bits)) >> (excess_bits)
//              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~           ~ Tell compiler we want a bool
```

Or

```cpp
              : ((excess_bits != 0) ? (((uint64_t)VAL) << (excess_bits)) >> (excess_bits)
```

---

The second snippet you provide is less clear because we don't have the error, exact offending line, or the definition of `ap_int<32>`. If I had to guess, the assignment of

```cpp
B.data()[i * n + j] =  0x00000001;
```

Should probably be assigning `true` instead of a numeric value; but this is just a guess, since no context has been given here.

Comment: Second snippet was the code section that causes the first snippet warning in compiler

Comment: @Rerkfk64 Thanks for clarifying. By the way, If this answered your question, please make sure to select this as the right answer

Comment: no unfortunately it didn't help, I have updated the question could you check it again ? Thanks